# Vim: Javascript syntax in strings

Tags: php, javascript, string, vim, syntax

I can't seem to find a plugin or syntax file to do this, but is there a way to have Javascript syntax highlighting within, say, PHP strings?  There's a plugin/syntax file to do it for SQL syntax.

Comment: Try https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript. It works well with JavaScript within HTML, maybe it works well with PHP too...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any plugin; though there probably is one. What I usually do is one of the following if I need the highlighting for a couple minutes in a different file type.

`:set filetype=javascript`

or

`:set filetype=html`

This doesn't really answer your question, but if no one comes up with anything better, or in the meantime, it should at least help a bit.